# Mongoose with typescript, error 'connect' from mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

When I start the server, this error appears:

**this.mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tsnode', {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

class App {
  public express: express.Application;

  public mongo: mongoose.Mongoose;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.database();
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }

  private middlewares(): void {
    this.express.use(express.json());
    this.express.use(cors());
  }

  private database(): void {
    this.mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tsnode', {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
  }

  private routes(): void {
    this.express.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
  }
}

export default new App().express;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not initiated the mongo variable, and you should do it in the constructor.
like:

```
  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.mongo= mongoose;  // initialize mongo variable
    this.database();
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }
```